# Function returns a definition instead of value (in example)

Tags: javascript

I`m trying to understand an example from a course *"JS - understanding the weird parts"* , cant figure out why my version of code returns a different output. Question is about `greet()` function inside this greeter application:

```
(function(global,$){

    var Greeter = function (firstName, lastName, language){
        return new Greeter.init (firstName, lastName, language); 
    };

    var supportedLangs = ["en", "es"];

    var greetings = {
        en: "Hello",
        es: "Hola"
    };

    var formalGreetings = {
        en: "Greetings",
        es: "Saludos"
    };

    Greeter.prototype = {

        fullName: function(){
            return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        },

        greeting: function(){
            return greetings[this.language] + " " + this.firstName + " !";
        },

        formalGreeting: function(){
            return formalGreetings[this.language] + ", " + this.fullName;
        },

        greet: function (formal){
            var msg;

            if (formal) {
                msg = this.formalGreeting();
            } 
            else {
                msg = this.greeting();
            }

            if (console) {
                console.log(msg);
            }

            return this;
        },

    };

    Greeter.init = function (firstName, lastName, language){

        var self = this;
        self.firstName = firstName || "";
        self.lastName = lastName || "";
        self.language = language || "en";

    };

    Greeter.init.prototype = Greeter.prototype;

    global.Greeter = global.G$ = Greeter;

})(window, jQuery);
```

Why does:

```
var g = G$("john","doe");
g.greet(false);
```

return a value, while:

```
var g = G$("john","doe");
g.greet(true);
```

returns a function definition - instead of value?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to call `this.formalGreeting` in you actual code. Also when you say “return” I assume you mean “logging to the console”? Because the function always returns `this`

Comment: you need to call function `this.fullName()` rather than writing `this.fullName` in `formatGreeting`.

Comment: Good catch @ArvindDhakad!